# Cloud Services Orchestration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, workflow, software-design, orchestration

How can I orchestrate and call cloud services from different providers: Google Cloud, AWS and Azure

We did check workflows, but it seems that workflows are limited in each provider's platform, so if I build a workflow in Azure, I can only include services from Azure, but not from Google Cloud or AWS.

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud Workflow](https://cloud.google.com/workflows) is an orchestrator that call APIs. There is a better integration for Google Cloud services (and with Google Security) but you can also use other API, such as other Cloud Provider services API.

You can also use [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer), based on [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/), which has a large library of operator that help you to call different services on different platform. Because it's initially (and still) an open source project, it's portable and there is no Cloud Preference on that solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an orchestration tool for multi `Cloud` usage, `Airflow` should be the best approach because it proposes many operators for each Cloud Provider.

It's open source, well documented, there are many supports and example in each Cloud Provider.

It's also the best tool if you want to be Cloud Agnostic and migrate it easily to any Cloud provider if needed.

If you host `Airflow` in `Google Cloud`, you can use a managed solution with [Cloud Composer 2](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/composer-versioning-overview) (GKE autopilot).

Cloud Workflow is a good solution if you stay in the `GCP` world, it's serverless and based on API calls but it is less documented than `Airflow` for an usage outside of `GCP`. It's also not Cloud agnostic and strongly coupled to `GCP`.

I recommend you using `Airflow` for your need.